# std::in_place_t and friends in C++17

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

As of the time of writing, cppreference gives a [reasonably simple definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_place) of the `std::in_place_t` family:

```
struct in_place_t {
    explicit in_place_t() = default;
};
inline constexpr std::in_place_t in_place{};

template <class T>
struct in_place_type_t {
    explicit in_place_type_t() = default;
};

template <class T>
inline constexpr std::in_place_type_t<T> in_place_type{};

template <size_t I> struct in_place_index_t {
    explicit in_place_index_t() = default;
};

template <size_t I>
inline constexpr in_place_index_t<I> in_place_index{};
```

However, the latest draft of the C++17 standard [linked from isocpp.org](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf) has a rather more complicated definition (section 20.2.7, page 536):

```
struct in_place_tag {
    in_place_tag() = delete;
};
using in_place_t = in_place_tag(&)(unspecified );

template <class T>
using in_place_type_t = in_place_tag(&)(unspecified <T>);

template <size_t I>
using in_place_index_t = in_place_tag(&)(unspecified <I>);

in_place_tag in_place(unspecified );

template <class T>
in_place_tag in_place(unspecified <T>);

template <size_t I>
in_place_tag in_place(unspecified <I>);
```

The first version is simple and easy to understand, but second version is quite opaque to me. So, questions:

- Which version is correct, post-Issaqua (November 2016)? (Presumably the second, but it's possible that N4606 hasn't yet been updated after the latest meeting and cppreference has.)
- Clearly this has changed at some point in time; does anyone have a link to a paper mentioning the change?
- Most importantly, can anyone explain how the second version is intended to work? What would a sample implementation look like?

Comment: Completely unconstructive, but I _so_ don't mind that I've stopped following C++ standardisation. What a mess.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Hey, it proves the standards process has improved. Remember `vector<bool>`? That actually got standardized; this was actually reverted. So that's progress.

Comment: FYI, cppreference has a revision history you can check, and every working draft is dated on the first page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first version is the right one, currently, and will in all likelihood be the one ending up in C++17.

The second version was [an attempt](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0032r3.pdf) to allow one to write `in_place` everywhere, with nothing, with a type, or with an index:

```
std::optional<int> o(std::in_place, 1);
std::any a(std::in_place<int>, 1);
std::variant<int, int> v(std::in_place<0>, 1);
```

The only way to make this syntax work is to make `in_place` an overloaded function, and that also requires making `in_place*_t` aliases for references to functions. There's no real implementation difference otherwise - the `in_place` functions aren't meant to be called, they exist only so that a reference to them can be passed around as a tag and match the corresponding `_t` types.

Nonetheless it was too clever and caused its own problems (for instance, unlike plain tag types, they don't respond well to being `decay`'d, and plain `std::in_place`, being an overloaded function name, misbehaves with perfect forwarders: `std::optional<std::optional<int>> o(std::in_place, std::in_place);` doesn't work because the compiler can't resolve the second `std::in_place`), so [it got backed out](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/d2d23690a253b91fb7ccb1631581bd9c8f2937d2) in Issaquah, and now you have to write

```
std::optional<int> o(std::in_place, 1);
std::any a(std::in_place_type<int>, 1);
std::variant<int, int> v(std::in_place_index<0>, 1);
```

A little less pretty, but more sane.